# PHPMailer not sending from HTML form, returns blank page

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with PHPMailer on my website. In short, I want someone who wants to contact me to be able to send me an e-mail via contact form on my website. Said code looks like this:

index.html:

```
<form action="formularzeng.php" method="POST">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="InputEmail">E-mail address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName">Full name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Full name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputText">Message</label>
    <textarea id="InputText" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

And formularzeng.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = "Contact form";
$message = $name . " " . " wrote:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                               
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                           
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';            
$mail->Password = 'password';                         
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('$to',); 
$mail->addReplyTo('$from', 'Mailer');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = '$subject';
$mail->Body    = '$message';
$mail->AltBody = '$message';
```

And a html section below with all the content saying "Thank you for your message. After uploading all the files on the server, filling the form and clicking on "Send" all I get is a white page, without any content. I'm totally green with php, but I want a working form on my portfolio website. Why is it not working?

Comment: did the mail send complete?

Comment: Nope, firefox inspector says that error 500 occured, but I don't know why.

Comment: I'm using this config 
`$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: is your google mail enabled less secure? what is next line after `$mail-AltBody` ?

Comment: is still any error occured?

Comment: After AltBody there is php closing (?>) and html code begins. Error is still the same/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134404/discussion-between-ntaloventi-and-grhu).

Comment: Turn out it was one coma too much in '$mail->addAddress('$to',);' - removing it  (now it's '$mail->addAddress('$to'); 'fixed the problem.

Comment: right, I'm miss read also

Comment: post your answer and accept it [closed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it was one coma too much in line:

```
$mail->addAddress('$to',);
```

removing it fixed the problem, now it's

```
$mail->addAddress('$to');
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your `'$var_name'` to `"$var_name"` to make PHP parse your strings....

For example, turn this :

```
$mail->Subject = '$subject';
$mail->Body    = '$message';
$mail->AltBody = '$message';
```

Into :

```
$mail->Subject = "$subject";
$mail->Body    = "$message";
$mail->AltBody = "$message";
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand - you wrote exactly the same thing in both examples.

Comment: There is a difference between a single quote ' and double quotes "

Comment: That didn't help. And in PHPmailer everything is in single (') quotes.